# Accessing the Kth group in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Is this the only way to do it?  It's quite verbose.

```
k = 0
grouped = df.groupby('A')
df.ix[grouped.groups[list(grouped.groups)[k]]]
```

Also, wouldn't `list(grouped.groups)` return keys in a meaningless order? (unordered dictionary)

Aside from the ordering of groups, is there a more consise way to get **a group**? I don't necessarily need to get the Kth one, although it would be nice to get them in the order they appear in the dataframe.

Comment: use the properties ``grouped.groups`` and/or ``grouped.indices`` to  access the groups directly. you can use ``list(grouped)`` to have the groups accessed in a sorted order; you are accessing a dictionary (so it is unordered)

Answer (score 3):

If you know the key, the concise way is `get_group`:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [1, 4], [5, 6]], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [12]: g = df.groupby('A')

In [13]: g.get_group(1)
Out[13]:
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  4
```

---

As mentioned the group keys are not necessarily ordered, you can access them (as is) with levels:

```
In [14]: g.grouper.levels
Out[14]: [Int64Index([1, 5], dtype='int64')]
```

if this is for just one column you can use `unique` to get them in the order they appear i.e. not sorted:

```
In [15]: df.A.unique()
Out[15]: array([1, 5])
```